# How to make span class for drop down list required?

Tags: html, dropdown, required

```
<a class="btn btn-info btn-select btn-select-light">
<input type="hidden" class="btn-select-input" id="" name="shopcollection" 
value="" required="required"/>

<span class="btn-select-value">Select Shop</span>
<span class='btn-select-arrow glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down' 
required="required"></span>

<ul>
    <li>example1</li>
    <li>example2</li>
    <li>example3</li>
</ul>
</a>

$(document).ready(function () {
$(".btn-select").each(function (e) {
    var value = $(this).find("ul li.selected").html();
    if (value != undefined) {
        $(this).find(".btn-select-input").val(value);
        $(this).find(".btn-select-value").html(value);
    }
});
});

$(document).on('click', '.btn-select', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ul = $(this).find("ul");
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
       if (ul.find("li").is(e.target)) {
        var target = $(e.target);
        target.addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
        var value = target.html();
        $(this).find(".btn-select-input").val(value);
        $(this).find(".btn-select-value").html(value);
    }
    ul.hide();
    $(this).removeClass("active");
}
else {
    $('.btn-select').not(this).each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("active").find("ul").hide();
    });
    ul.slideDown(300);
    $(this).addClass("active");
}
});

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
var target = $(e.target).closest(".btn-select");
if (!target.length) {
    $(".btn-select").removeClass("active").find("ul").hide();
}
});
```

I am trying to make it so the user has to select one of the elements (example1) however my required code does not work so the user can bypass the drop down list. I have include the drop down code (top section) and the drop down javascript file (bottom section), any tips?

Comment: Neither a list nor a span are form controls. They don't allow the user to select anything in the first place. You might have some JavaScript which makes them act like form controls, but you forgot to mention that. If you want them to act like form controls so much they do input validation, then you would need to add more JavaScript to implement those features.

Comment: I have included the js file, is there anyway to make the drop down list required?

Answer (score -1):

You are going to need to use a `select` to conform to your need:

```
<select required>
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Further reading: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_required.asp

Comment: I cannot style the select required the same as my span class tho? Is there anyway to style them so they look the same?

Comment: If you're looking to style `select`, have a look at [select2](https://select2.github.io/)

Comment: Thank you but I cannot seem to get select2 working with bootstrap